# FreeBSD - UFS equivalent of ZFS command

Tags: freebsd, jails, ufs

I'm trying to configure jails with [this tutorial](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/30063/).

Since I don't want to use ZFS, could anyone tell me the UFS equivalent of

```
zfs create -o mountpoint=/local/jails zpool/jails
chmod 700 /local/jails && chown root:wheel /local/jails
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

It is effectively creating a directory `/local/jails` so simplistically the following could be considered equivalent:

```
mkdir -p /local/jails
```

However, this will create the directory path in the root file system, so you need to ensure that this file system is big enough.

Some UFS installations use different partitions (or slices) for `/` and `/usr`, so `/` may be relatively small compared to `/usr`. You can use the `df` and/or `mount` commands to determine if your system is partitioned this way.

In short, you may be advised to use the default location for jails (as mentioned in your tutorial) which is `/usr/jails`.